# Bridge to Kubernetes fails to start with a "Failed to launch EndpointManager error"

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.1 and I am trying to start Bridge to Kubernetes in Visual Studio Code v1.74.3.

However, it would hang for a few seconds on the "Waiting for the EndpointManager to come up..." step, and then crash with an uninformative error log:

```
Error: connect-service-task-terminal-error <json>{}</json> <stack>Error: Failed to establish a connection. 
Error: An unexpected error occurred: 'Failed to launch EndpointManager.'\n
To see our active issues or file a bug report, please visit https://aka.ms/bridge-to-k8s-report.\n
For diagnostic information, see logs at '/tmp/Bridge To Kubernetes'.\n\n
```

I have tried setting an environmental variable as suggested in [this GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/microsoft/mindaro/issues/189), but it did not do it for me.

```
BRIDGE_BINARYUTILITYVERSION=v1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague assumed, that since the Bridge to Kubernetes uses dotnet under the hood, it is worth trying installing dotnet SDK and dotnet environment separately, which fixed the issue for me.

First the dotnet SDK:

```
sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

And the dotnet runtime:

```
sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-6.0
```